# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase - can't retrieve all entries from the database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, sqlite

context: I can retrieve entries with the other methods like `public Cursor getEntry(long rowId)` and `public Cursor getEntry(String category)` but for some reason `public Cursor getAllEntries()` doesn't work. I'm getting the error `Cursor - Invalid statement in fillWindow()`

code:

```
//---retrieves all entries---
    public Cursor getAllEntries() throws SQLException
    {
        Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "DBAdapter - DatabaseHelper - getAllEntries();");
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
                new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TYPE,
                KEY_DATE,
                KEY_CATEGORY,
                KEY_AMOUNT},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

full code:
ListActivity (from where I'm calling the db) - http://pastebin.com/UGSvhsfd
DBAdapter (my interface to the db) - http://pastebin.com/jqtLiPHB
DBAdapter (my friends DBAdapter which works as it should) - http://pastebin.com/QTRF958d

**EDIT1**:
code of where the db is called:

```
private void updateGUI(int displayScope) {
        Cursor c;
        ArrayList<Entry> entries;           // NOTE: making an Entry ArrayList due to the fact that rows in Cursors cannot be deleted
        switch(displayScope) {
        case BudgetConstants.DISPLAY_ALL:
            c = getAllTransactions();
            //boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
            //Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "movetofirst: "+b);
            entries = extractEntries(c, BudgetConstants.FILTER_LIMIT_ALL);
            displayEntries(entries);
            break;
        case BudgetConstants.DISPLAY_MONTH:
            c = getAllTransactions();
            entries = extractEntries(c, BudgetConstants.FILTER_LIMIT_MONTH);
            displayEntries(entries);
            break;
        }
    }

private ArrayList<Entry> extractEntries(Cursor c, int filter) {
        ArrayList<Entry> res = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int currYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {  // <------ getting an error here: Cursor - Invalid statement in fillWindow()
            do {
                if (filter==BudgetConstants.FILTER_LIMIT_MONTH) {
                    String entryDate = c.getString(BudgetConstants.DB_DATE);
                    int entryMonth = getMonth(entryDate);
                    int entryYear = getYear(entryDate);
                    if (!((entryMonth==currMonth) && (entryYear==currYear)))
                        continue;
                } else if (filter==BudgetConstants.FILTER_LIMIT_ALL)
                    res.add(new Entry(c.getString(BudgetConstants.DB_DATE), c.getString(BudgetConstants.DB_TYPE), c.getString(BudgetConstants.DB_AMOUNT)));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Moved `db.close();` to the last line of `private void displayEntries(ArrayList<Entry> entries)`, seems like that did the trick.